# Parallel.ForEach and ListView Control

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I am having an issue getting the Parallel.ForEach to work properly. I have a listview control that loads a files contents or mutliple files contents (each file represents a log file) into a richtextbox. Had it all working with a Foreach loop but decided that the parallel operation would cut down on the loadtime when loading 100+ files.

Here is the code block I was using for the foreach loop. How do I get a Parallel.Foreach working?

```
//Set cursor to WaitCursor Style
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

//Clear Messages RichTexBox
this.rtbMessages.Clear();

//Loop through each selected file
foreach (ListViewItem Item in lvMessageFiles.Items)
{
    //Check if item is selected in the listview
    if (Item.Selected && rtbMessages.TextLength < rtbMessages.MaxLength)
    {
        //Get Path to message file
        filename = String.Format("{0}\\Data\\Log\\{1}.log", Global.AppPath, Item.SubItems[0].Text);

        //Set Timeline Events calendar to selected items created date
        cvTimeline.ShowDate(Convert.ToDateTime(lvMessageFiles.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text));

        //Check if file exists
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            //streamreader to read the file
            reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            //to copy the read content in to richtextbox
            string MessageContents = String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n", ("file:///" + filename.Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("\\", "/")), reader.ReadToEnd());
            rtbMessages.Text += MessageContents;

            // closing streamreader
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

}

//Set cursor to WaitCursor Style
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Answer (score 3):

2 problems with what you are doing.

1) with this specific code, you are trying to modify UI from a background thread which is not allowed
2) this scenario isn't a good candidate for parallelization anyhow because you're performace is "I/O bound" to a single hard drive.  if you want to speed up load time, split the files onto multiple hard drives and then parallelization may be worthwhile

see [Is Parallel File.Read Faster than Sequential Read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237926/is-parallel-file-read-faster-than-sequential-read)

Comment: good point... and since all these files will be on the same drive, even folder, and there is no cpu-intensive processing of each file it doesn't make much sense to parallelize it.

Comment: both good points, also the order is not guaranteed in Parallel.ForEach so all log files will be in a somewhat random order

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to update UI from a non-UI thread, which threads in a `Parallel.ForEach` obviously will be. Instead use the Invoke method to set the `Text` of `rtbMessages` and call `cvTimeline.ShowDate`

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing dejavu with this question... Anyway, take a look at this blog article. It's very simple to my taste but does exactly what you are trying to achieve - update UI while working with concurrent collections using new .NET 4 parallel mechanisms. Though not ForEach but Task.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx